# Does dm_exec_procedure_stats.total_worker_time include signal waits?

Tags: sql-server, dmv, waits

Does `sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats`.`total_worker_time` include signal waits or only time spent by procedure on scheduler?

The reason of question - when number of cores was increased on the server `signal waits` decreased as expected, but `total_worker_time`/`execution_count` has dropped too.

Answer (score 1):

Neal Hambly in his post at [SQL Server SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD Wait Type](http://logicalread.solarwinds.com/sql-server-sos-scheduler-yield-wait-type-nh01/#.Vwu2CmwpDyM) includes this comment (highlights are mine):

> If you have long running queries, especially when in conjunction with
> **high signal wait times**, it may be an indication of **CPU pressure**.
>
> Reviewing the system performance will show if the CPUs are showing
> signs of **CPU pressure**, and reducing workload through **performance
> tuning or other steps** can help reduce the workloads being performed by
> SQL Server.

Certainly adding more cores will change the amount of pressure each CPU must face.  So, *it seems quite reasonable that more processors will reduce the pressure on each CPU*, which in turn provides better CPU throughput.

Comment: Not answering my question. It was not a question on throughput, the question was - why average cpu consumption of procedures has decreased?

Comment: @AlexanderTarasul - Last paragraph: I italicized the note on reduction of CPU pressure.